# Adding File Object to redux store results in empty property object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, redux

I'm trying to add a File Object to my Redux store.

My reducer looks like this:

```
...
case 'SET_INVOICE':
  console.log(action.invoice); //File Object
  return { ...state, invoice: action.invoice};
...
```

Instead of the File Object added to the Redux store, the result is an empty object `invoice: { }`

Comment: Hey, @Thore. Why do you need to store the file on redux? Could you store it on server and add the reference to redux? Also, maybe take a look at this issue: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2276

Comment: Uploading one or more files is a step in a multiple-step form/process of a web app I'm working on. To avoid unnecessary uploads (and costs) of users who do not complete the process I'm waiting till the end to upload all the files at once. Therefore I want to store the files in the Redux store till the last step.

Answer (score 1):

Redux only stores datatype that is serializable, and `File` is not one of them. Try storing ES6 `Map` or `Set`. They will both appear as empty object as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks empty on devtool but it's not!
Try to show redux store data in console log, you will see that it is not empty